# MVVM Refresh a ReadOnly Textbox in a System.Windows.Controls.Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I have a Grid :

```
 <Grid Name="MyGrid" DataContext="{Binding MyGridBinded}" >
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Total, Mode=OneWay}" />
 </Grid>
```

And MyGridBinded is an object:

```
 public class GridPOCO
 { 
   public IList myList { get ; set; }
   public Total { get { Return myList.Count; }}
 }
```

So when i update my myList, in My ViewModel I call :

```
 Base.OnpropertyChanged("MyGridBinded");
```

But Total is not updated.

How can i do to update my readonly field ?

---

@H.B and @Daniel Rose.

If I implement INotifyPropertyChanged in GridPOCO. I could after call :

```
Base.OnpropertyChanged("Total");
```

But GridPOCO is a POCO object, and i don't want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in it.

When I would have time, I will try the Ben answer.

Comment: The word is *"bound"*, not *"binded"*.

Comment: Do you mean public int Total?

Comment: Sorry @H.B i was talking to @TKanos, don't think his code sample is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You need to name the property, not the object:

```
Base.OnpropertyChanged("Total");
```

(*The object containing the `Total` proeprty or one of its base classes needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and that method needs to be called on the instance whose property changed*)

Alternatively just call it with `null` to update all property bindings (you normally avoid this):

```
Base.OnpropertyChanged(null);
```

Comment: No. He is binding to Total, so INPC has to be called for that. The binding engine doesn't know that Total refers to myList internally.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call INPC for the property which has been changed, i.e.

```
Base.OnpropertyChanged("Total");
```

in *GridPOCO*. That means GridPOCO has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged!

Comment: Actually i am positive that it does *not* work, the event expects a property name, not a a property path, i even tried it. You rather want something like `MyGridBinded.OnPropertyChanged("Total")` if it's visible.

Comment: @H.B. You are right. But if you call the INPC for Total where it isn't there (since it is in a different class), it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyGridBinded.Total, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And also to call the property changed event for the property (clue is in the name) not the class.

base.PropertyChanged("MyList");

Comment: That will only work if the DataContext on the Grid is removed.